# How to Raise Runtime Error in Rspec-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I have to test a code where I am raising some errors, I tried several techniques but it failed. The structure of the class is defined below:

SchemaController:

```
class SchemasController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @get_schema = Api::AnalyticsQueryBuilderMetadataService::Schema.show
  end
end
```

Show method under Api -> AnalyticsQueryBuilderMetadataService -> Schema.rb file:

```
def self.show
        params = { 'limit' => 40 }
        response = Api::Connection.initiate_request('entities', params)
        if response.nil?
           Rails.logger.error 'Data not found for ClientId '
           raise 'Data not found'
        else
           get_schema(response)
        end
end
```

Rspec test I wrote for schema_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::AnalyticsQueryBuilderMetadataService::Schema do
  describe 'GET all schema' do
    before do
      # allow_any_instance_of(SchemasController).to receive(:connection).and_return({})
      #binding.pry
      allow(Api::Connection).to receive(:initiate_request).and_return(nil)
    end

    context 'When no json body is passed' do
      it 'Raises NoMethodError' do
        # obj = SchemasController.new
        result = Api::AnalyticsQueryBuilderMetadataService::Schema.show()
        # expect {result}.to raise_error(RuntimeError)
        expect{result}.to raise_error
      end

      
    end
  end
end
```

But It is giving error as:

```
Failures:

  1) Api::AnalyticsQueryBuilderMetadataService::Schema GET all schema When no json body is passed Raises NoMethodError
     Failure/Error: raise 'Data not found'
     
     RuntimeError:
       Data not found
     # ./app/lib/api/analytics_query_builder_metadata_service/schema.rb:22:in `show'
     # ./spec/lib/api/analytics_query_builder_metadata_service/schema_spec.rb:17:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 2.3 seconds (files took 5.63 seconds to load)
44 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/lib/api/analytics_query_builder_metadata_service/schema_spec.rb:15 # Api::AnalyticsQueryBuilderMetadataService::Schema GET all schema When no json body is passed Raises NoMethodError
```

Help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs;

> Use the raise_error matcher to specify that a block of code raises an
> error.

It means that the code in the block should be the one raising the error, but in your case the error is being raised when you declare the `result` variable.

To make it work you can skip the variable declaration and pass the variable value as the `expect` block;

```
expect { Api::AnalyticsQueryBuilderMetadataService::Schema.show }
  .to raise_error(StandardError, 'Data not found')
```